# Analytics - Match URL with Parameters

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics, query-string

I am having difficulties registering this URL as a goal. It is the final URL.

`https://foo.com/Home/Search?Message=Success&show=True`

I have tried matching the exact URL, but that doesn't work. I've tried various regEx patterns, but I don't know how to match a specific parameter/value.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can use an URL as a goal. Documentation suggests you'd use a page path (without protocol and hostname).

Comment: Can you show us the match pattern that you are using in the goal setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match exactly this URL your regex should be like :

```
https:\/\/foo.com\/Home\/Search\?Message=Success&show=True
```